# find keys by pattern in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next object structure:

```
{
"translate.google.com":{...},
"stackoverflow.com":{...},
"google.com":{...},
}
```

i.e. for each subdomain I have some data to use. For domain/subdomain extraction from URL I used next code:

```
/**
     *Gets domain name from current page
     * @return {string} domain name
     */
    getDomainData: function() {
        var parts = location.origin.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "").split('.').reverse();
        var cnt = parts.length;
        var result = parts[1] + '.' + parts[0];
        if (cnt >= 3) {
            // see if the second level domain is a common SLD.
            if (parts[1].match(/^(com|edu|gov|net|mil|org|nom|co|name|info|biz)$/i)) {
                result = parts[2] + '.' + parts[1] + '.' + parts[0];
            }
        }
        return {
            domainName: result,
            subDomainName: this.getSubDomainName(location.origin)
        };
    },

    /**
     * returns subdomain name if exists, otherwise return domain name
     * @param  {[type]} url [description]
     * @return {[type]}     [description]
     */
    getSubDomainName: function(url) {
        var match = url.match(/:\/\/(www[0-9]?\.)?(.[^/:]+)/i);
        if (match !== null && match.length > 2 && typeof match[2] === 'string' && match[2].length > 0) return match[2];
    },
```

However, for some cases the data for all subdomain domains is the same and in such dictionary struct I have to define same data mulptiple times.

Id like to create some smart algorithm that for next key  `*.google.com` will take value of such key and apply it to all google domain

Thanks for help.

Comment: that's great, have you taken the time to solve your problem?

Comment: that's way less complex than your regex in getSubDomainName!

Comment: @DanielA.White of course I did. e.g. today my solution is return next object from getDomainData function:  `return {
            domainName: result,
            subDomainName: this.getSubDomainName(location.origin),
            gloablDomainPattern: '*.'+result
        };`                                                                                                                    However, I think this solution is not optimal one